# Speech Recognition MS word Add-in for local language in VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to create a speech recognition add-in to work with MS Word for my local language (other than English)

Does System.speech will work for me or something else is required?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Speech`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145021.aspx) should be enough for the speech part if you can [transliterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) to/from English.

You will need [office automation libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=office%20pia&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic) to work with word.

Comment: Our language had 52 characters in alphabet and its RTL langugae. Any idea?

Comment: You can try to transliterate with speech recognition.